# Solving $(1+ r/100)^t =2$ for the variable $r$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have to solve the equation **$(1+ r/100)^t =2$** for the variable $r$:

I do have the end result **$r=100(2^{1/2}-1)$**, but the process it takes to reach this end result eludes me.

Comment: Apparently $t=2$ ...?

Comment: In general this is not true if you dont have $t=2$ $$(1+r/100)^t=2\\\implies 1+r/100 = 2^{1/t}\tag{ taking the t-th root}\\ \implies r/100=2^{1/t}-1\text{ subtracting 1}\\\implies r = 100\left(2^{1/t}-1\right)\text{multiplying by 100}$$

Comment: The idea of taking the t-th root has made it clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewritten:
$$
\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac{r}{100}\right)^t&=2\\
1+\frac{r}{100}&=\sqrt[t]{2}\\
\frac{r}{100}&=\sqrt[t]{2}-1\\
r&=100\left(\sqrt[t]{2}-1\right)\\
&=\Large100\left(2^\frac{1}{t}-1\right).
\end{align}
$$

$$\\$$

---

$$\Large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$

Comment: Thanks for the step by step solution.

Comment: @user140938 You are welcome...